# Div(s) between two fixed elements (header and footer)

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

Here's what I want to do:

[image: Layout illustration]

I hope I've explained it well with the picture. 
I searched a lot on this topic but I really don't want to get into tons of functions. I would like to solve it as simple as possible.

The problem is because I want all to be real-time responsive if user changes browser size or for display on different screens.

Also, about adding those images inside of left menu; they are 1:1 sides ratio, but I want to scale them so together they will be 100% height of left menu (blue in picture).

Here is what I have so far:

HTML/CSS:

```css
header {
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

#allContents {
   position: relative; /*minus širina headerja in footerja!!*/
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   z-index: 10;
}

#leftMenu {
   position: relative;
   background-color: green;
   width: 10%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index:10; 
}

#mainContent {
   background-color: yellow;
   size: 20%;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}

#rightMenu {
   background-color: orange;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 25%;
}

footer {
   clear: both;
   background-color: blue;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
   Fixed. Some header content... also image on the left.
</header>

<div id="allContents">
   <div id="leftMenu">On left, between header and footer, but never behind. Always between.</div>
   <div id="mainContent">Between all 4 elements. Here will be main content with scrolling.</div>
   <div id="rightMenu">Div with some news.</div>
</div>

<footer>
   Fixed footer.
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you would benefit tremendously from using Flexboxes. They allow you to format the exact structure you want using CSS and they are responsive to window size. [Flexbox Froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) is a great resource to learn how to use them.

Comment: This is acctually great :D Looks very promissing, thank you. I also find this guide [link]https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: other elements works as i wanted, but i need to scroll to see the footer

Comment: @HelloDarkness That's because I added `height: 100vh` to the `body, html` on line 3 of the CSS. You can take that out and those divs will only be as "tall" as the content in them. Also if this does work for you then could you except it as the answer?

Comment: but now also if the header becomes higher, you need to scroll for end of content.. i need it to be page without scrolling. i want height of all elements cobined be 100vh.. not only 3 middle element

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```css
header {
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

#allContents {
   position: relative; /*minus širina headerja in footerja!!*/
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   z-index: 10;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

#leftMenu {
   position: relative;
   background-color: green;
   width: 10%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index:10; 
 
}

#mainContent {
   background-color: yellow;
   size: 20%;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
 
}

#rightMenu {
   background-color: orange;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 25%;
  
}
```

```html
<header>
   Fixed. Some header content... also image on the left.
</header>

<div id="allContents">
   <div id="leftMenu">On left, between header and footer, but never behind. Always between.</div>
   <div id="mainContent">Between all 4 elements. Here will be main content with scrolling.</div>
   <div id="rightMenu">Div with some news.</div>
</div>

<footer>
   Fixed footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: Footer is still not on bottom of the screen, also if window is larger than (approx.) 500px header goes a way further right than other elements. I appreciate your help anyway :)

Comment: yes you can fix it on bottom by adding this style footer{  position: fixed;bottom:0;background: yellow; width: 100%; text-align: center;}

Comment: will this make other elements go under it (if the footer has fixed position)?

Comment: ok use position:absolute; and put body{  /* padding-bottom:  your footer height goes here  */ }

Comment: problem #1: footer doesnt have fixed height and #2: middle 3 elements dont stretch to fill all the space available